# Extra space between two words in a string in MYSQL table

Tags: mysql

I have an MYSQL 8 table in which the full name of the same person (LN FN MI) is listed two different ways (two different records).  Record#1 is `MCCAULEY KELLY JO` and Record#2 is `MC CAULEY KELLY JO`.  There should be no space between `MC` and `CAULEY`.  This occurs for hundreds of names that begin with 'MC' or other combos like 'MR'.  What is the best way to delete the records with the space?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aWRA.png)

At first, I tried the REPLACE COMMAND. If I wanted to replace all of the spaces, it would work but I don't want to replace all of them.  If that would have worked I would have deleted the duplicate record.

Comment: I'm confused on what is your criteria - or if you're looking for one. I'd suggest studying the data to find words that repeat in LN field, sampling them to determine which ones should be trimmed and then explicitly stating which words should be concatenated within LN field.

Comment: You claim: "I tried", why do you not share this try ? And "I don't want to replace all of them", can you share an example of the ones you do not want to replace?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this using the wildcard symbol in SQL (%):

```
Delete from table where PartyName like 'MC %' or PartyName like 'MR %'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression might also be helpful:

```
delete from table
where PartyName REGEXP 'MC[[:space:]]|MR[[:space:]]';
```